# Not able to set custom dimensions in a google analytics property for android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-analytics-sdk

Please find the tracking code below,

`GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(MY_PROPERTY_ID);

t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().setCustomDimension(1, "testing custom dimension").build());`

The above code is added to a click listener for an element in the UI.

Index 1 in setCustomDimension refers to a dimension named "test" in my property settings, which is the only dimension I have for that property.

The screen view session is getting tracked in 'App Overview', but is not added to the report for my custom dimension.

I created a custom report using customization tab.[image: Report for my custom dimension,]

But still I am not getting any data for the custom dimension,

[image: No data shown in the report]

I have checked the report after a day and even after running many times.
I am using android studio and no errors/warnings are thrown in logcat.

Please help me to resolve this problem.
And it would be helpful if you can suggest any clean documentation/blog with sample codes for tracking advanced metrics for an android app through google analytics.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Has @Tijee answer resolved your problem? I've got the same thing as you described and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem, it seems there is a known issue in the SDK: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=435.

You have to set a screen name before sending the custom dimension to the tracker:

```
t.setScreenName("Home Screen");
t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().setCustomDimension(1, "testing custom dimension").build());
```